# How can show label of new when will create new row & should hide after click on this item

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to show **New** label when will create a new item in the table and should hide when will click on this item

I'm creating a real-time system with a pusher library in Vuejs. I want to show New text string label when will create a new row When I will click on the for show productCategories then should remove the new label only clicked row others that are coming from the frontend should show the new label

This is my code of snippet.. you can see that

```
<template>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Created Date</th>
                <th class="text-center">Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="product in products">
                    <td><a href="#" @click="getProductCategories(product)">{{product.id}} </a></td>
                    <td>{{product.name}} <span class="label label-success" v-if="!isHidden">New</span></td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <a href="#" @click="editProduct(product)"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" @click="deleteProduct(product)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            this.getResults();      
        },
        computed: {

        },
        data(){
            return{
                products:[],
                isHidden: false,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getResults() {
                let _this = this;
                axios.get('/api/v1/product', {
                      params: {}
                  })
                    .then(response => {
                        _this.products = response.data.products;
                    })
                    .catch(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
            },
            getProductCategories(product) {
                let _this = this;
                _this.isHidden = true;
                axios.get('/api/v1/getProductCategories/' + product.id, {
                    params: {}
                })
                .then(response => {
                    _this.isHidden = false;
                    _this.categories = response.data.categories;
                })
                .catch(response => {
                    _this.isHidden = false;
                    console.log(response);
                });
            },
            deleteRecord(product) {
                let _this = this;
                var  _confirm = confirm("Are you sure?");
                if (!_confirm) {
                    return; 
                }
                axios.delete('/api/v1/deleteProduct/' + product.id, {
                     params: {}
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        _this.products = response.data.products;                    
                    }).catch(error => {
                      console.log(error);
                });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Dear i want to show only "New" status with the new created row when will push a new item in the array of existing

Comment: and where are you creating? because i'm not seeing any creating functionality here. If so just take the last index of the server items (that is added) and set the value to `True` on that..